# libGDX transparent screen - Show Desktop/Home Screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to port a game of mine to libGDX. The game currently uses [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061396/975959) in order to achieve that in Android.

I've looked but couldn't find a way to get the same effect (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17984654/975959) answer, but it's outdated and causes my app to crush, and also I would prefer to have something in the `core` of libGDX so I might be able to port it to iOS or others)

Basically I want to be fully transparent - I want the home screen to show behind the transparent screen. (I thought of a workaround, to take a screenshot and then use this bitmap as background, but I would like to avoid it if possible)

Is it possible at all?

**EDIT**
If it's not possible in libGDX, is it possible in other game engine? (AndEngine, Cocos2D, etc? I've managed to do it myself, but I would like to use a good game engine for the rest of game, no to start everything from scratch)

Comment: I don't see anything in the example you posted that looks out of date. Maybe you can explain what the crash was that you saw. Maybe post your code so it can be debugged. There is no way to solve this from the core part of the project. The actual OpenGL surface creation is device dependent, so every platform will need its own solution.

Comment: The crush was my bad. It runs, but I only see a black screen when using that solution

Comment: Have you set a transparent theme in the manifest? Like: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. However, for some reason no nothing is drawn `on top` of the transparent background (Using the initial `core` application). When removing that tag it does. Am I missing something?