# LibGDX Set State's Background transparent

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, libgdx

I am rendering a `gameover.png` on the screen when the character dies, but the background for it get's set via `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 150);` & `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` in the main class.

What I want is to stack the `gameover.png` stack over the current playstate, as the character dies.

I cannot accept the answer here as my main class inherits from `ApplicationAdapter`. 
[Background transparency in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966338/background-transparency-in-libgdx)